# How to get option name in xpath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm parsing one xml file.
I want to got Name of option field from xml file using xpath query
Like **option name="Colour"**
My xml file content is below:

```
<item>
  <type>colour</type>
    <option name="Colour">
      <value>Navy</value>
      <value>Orange</value>
     </option>
</item>

<item>
 <type>size</type>
   <option name="Size">
      <value>Navy</value>
      <value>Orange</value>
   </option>
</item>
```

I want to check like: i'm not sure how to check this condition

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test1.xml');
        foreach($xml as $product)
        {
             echo $product->type;            
             if(xpath('//option[@name="Colour"]'))
              {
                  echo "color is there";
              }

            if(xpath('//option[@name="Size"]'))
             {
                echo "size is there";
              } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM without XPath, like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('option') as $option) {
    switch($option->getAttribute('name')) {
        case "Colour" :
          echo "Colour is here";
          break;

        case "Size" : ...
          echo "Size is there";
          break;
    }
}
```